# Real Time Collaboration in Office Web Apps

Tags: ms-office, google-docs

I would like to know if is there a plugin or a function in Office Web Apps to real time collaboration like Google Drive, I mean, at the same time, not saving and saving the same document to retrieve changes.

Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

Co-authoring (as Microsoft calls it) is available for docx (as of July 2011), pptx and xlsx.  See http://blogs.office.com/b/officewebapps/archive/2012/10/22/updated-office-web-apps-now-available-to-all.aspx

For docx, it was and may still be one user per paragraph (so not real time like Google Docs). See http://gigaom.com/2011/07/08/microsoft-word-web-app-gets-co-authoring-capability/

If it isn't working, see http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/web-apps-help/troubleshoot-co-authoring-word-documents-HA102506022.aspx or http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/sharepoint-server-help/document-collaboration-and-co-authoring-HA101812148.aspx